# Is it a good security practice to use ajax query to confirm if username exist for new user registration

Tags: php, ajax

I was going through the cool functions of Ajax and how it can verify if a username exist before you submit the registration form. Using this function can make job easier for malicious users to get note of a username to use to query the login system. Is this use of Ajax not prone to security infringement as illustrated above?

Comment: They could get a username, but they'd still need the rest of the credentials.

Comment: not if you do it over https:  ajax is just like a form post no different as far as the network is concerned.

Comment: still new to the use of ajax but was about considering to use it to validate my registration form. Maybe i just skip the part of validating username with ajax.

Comment: Usually credentials are a pair of a public identifier and a private authenticator/token/password. The username is your public part. So there no real security issue. Of course there may be confidentiality reasons but I don't think chosen usernames have to be hidden (they will be visible from your site I think)

Comment: Is there a reason why a third party should know a username actually exist in my database?. I think only authenticated user should know. Once a malicious user knows this, the only problem left is to start generating possible password for such username(my point actually). These are just my thoughts. more experienced developers know far better.